# ng-options и ng-model в angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть разметка

```
{{SelectedSemester}} -тут всё хорошо отображается
<select ng-model="SelectedSemester" ng-change="" ng-options="semester.Id as semester.Name for semester in DataService.GET_SemestersList()">
<button ng-click="group_create_show()">показать</button>
```

и код

```
$scope.group_create_show= function() { 
  alert($scope.SelectedSemester) // а здесь не выводится пробовал $scope.SelectedSemester.Id
}
```

DataService.GET_SemestersList() возвращает список семестров

Пересмотрел всю документацию. Везде работает, а здесь нет. Странно.

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем решил немного по-другому. В разметке написал 
ng-change="myfunc(SelectedSemester)" ,
а потом вызвал $scope.myfunc= function(semester) {alert(semester);}